# A variational problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I was studying the paper "Non-holonomic Euler-Poincaré equations and stability in Chaplygin's sphere" by D. Schneider (2002). A non-holonomic constraint - see equation (24) - is expressed as
$$
\dot{y} = \dot{g}g^{-1}a_0,\quad\text{ for }t\geq 0,
$$
where $y\in V$, with $V$ denoting a vector space that is acted upon by a Lie group $G$, and $g\in G$. The quantity $a_0$ is a constant in $V$.

Now a variation $\delta g$ (vanishing at $t=0$) induces a variation $\delta y$. Theorem 3 of the paper takes such variation to be $\delta y = \delta g\,g^{-1}\,a_0$. I can't figure out why, neither mathematically nor physically (I would expect the variation $\delta y$ at some point $t$ would depend on all variations $\delta g$ from $0$ to $t$). Clues anyone ?